# Why values does not match for GETSESSIONID and getSessionId?

Tags: apex, visualforce, session, session-id

I am trying to read the user session using `GETSESSIONID()` on the VF page
and using `UserInfo.getSessionId()` in apex. The values returned by both ways do not match.

```
GETSESSIONID() => 00DAB000000I1zO!AQoAQJ3Ou27E7EonznDKcQa5dKfJtAYutaiUPwfNuG4_KnfMupjd22EAmGo4obWr9NMFVIgKtGvjF8Cnb_WmMBE4pPC2CbVC
UserInfo.getSessionId() => 00ABf000000I1zO!AQoAQByH38YFB62y0cS.jATTFTi4WX4sIzAZZp_UR.QLi9SZ2la1NPrLkuJtxemKOc3HhpQRwGUhPqoQMulDGXPlXnNZZZ2q
```

Why sessionId value is different on the VF page and Apex controller?

Comment: P.S. make sure you log out of those sessions, as they are as valuable as passwords...

Comment: I have changed the session values before posting here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce has multiple domains, such as visual.force.com, lightning.com, org.my.salesforce.com, etc. When you log in, a parent session is created; depending on how you log in, you'll get a different type of Session Id. If the parent Session Id is logged out, all other sessions are also logged out at the same time. When you use Apex, you will get one of several different Session Id values, depending on where the Apex was called from. When you call GETSESSIONID, it should be a Visualforce Session Id. All of those Session IDs are valid, but generated from different contexts.

Comment: Is there way to retrieve parent session, or any other value which is unique to Salesforce user session and has value same in VF page and apex controller? I am trying implement Salesforce session token and which will be validated before action executes.

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati This is a bit of an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve, specificially?

Comment: Trying to implement anti csrf token for POST ajax requests without saving tokens in Salesforce platform.

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati There's easier ways to make a CRSF token, and that's assuming that the built-in CRSF system isn't already good enough.  You might want to ask about that, instead.